# Server Side path to store uploads from website

Tags: security, server-side

For security, I want to upload employee contracts to the hidden server side path. The upload works fine.

However, I also want to be able to download or view that file when I am logged in the front end of my website, with a seceret link. Is this possible?

Any other ideas?

Joomla website, hosted on Rack Space Cloud Sites.

Answer (score 0):

Sure,  upload the file to a directory outside the webroot,  or a directory with a .htaccess file that contains "deny from all".   Have a sql table that maps the primary key to the file name, the file's content-type and access control information and other metadata about this file.  Then save the file as the primary key,  so `/uploads/1`.

Then to download the file,  burn a sql query to figure out if they should be able to download the file.

```
<?
//...
$q=mysql_fetch_array($q);
header("content-type: ".$q['content_type']);
print file_get_contents("./uplaods/".intval($q['id']));
?>
```